# Nested React Hook Form: Type 'Record<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-rhf?file=src%2FForm.tsx) that illustrates my issue.

I have code `nestedForm.ts` based off of [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/7354#discussioncomment-2786306). I don't really understand the specifics of what this is doing or why the types work, which makes debugging the below issue difficult.

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
import { FieldPath, FieldValues, UseFormReturn } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Get } from 'type-fest';

export type NestedForm<TValues extends FieldValues> = UseFormReturn<{
  __nested__: TValues;
}> & {
  path(this: void): `__nested__`;
  path<TPath extends FieldPath<TValues>>(
    this: void,
    p?: TPath
  ): `__nested__.${TPath}`;
  get<TObj>(this: void, obj: TObj): Get<TObj, `__nested__`>;
  get<TPath extends FieldPath<TValues>, TObj>(
    this: void,
    obj: TObj,
    p?: TPath
  ): Get<TObj, `__nested__.${TPath}`>;
};

export function nestedForm<TValues extends FieldValues>(
  form: UseFormReturn<TValues> | NestedForm<TValues>
): NestedForm<TValues>;
export function nestedForm<
  TValues extends FieldValues,
  TPath extends FieldPath<TValues>
>(
  form: UseFormReturn<TValues> | NestedForm<TValues>,
  path: TPath
): NestedForm<Get<TValues, TPath>>;
export function nestedForm(
  form: UseFormReturn<any> | NestedForm<any>,
  path?: string | number
): NestedForm<any> {
  return {
    ...form,
    path(field?: string | number) {
      const fullPath = path && field ? `${path}.${field}` : path ? path : field;
      if ('path' in form) return form.path(path as any);
      return (fullPath || '') as any;
    },
    get(obj: any, field?: string | number) {
      const fullPath = path && field ? `${path}.${field}` : path ? path : field;
      if ('get' in form) return form.get(path);
      return fullPath ? get(obj, fullPath) : obj;
    },
  };
}
```

This allows me to define a react-hook-form schema with nested fields and create a React component that takes a path to one of the nested fields.

Here is how the above code is used. I have a nested schema with `value1` and `value2`. The `NestedFormComponent` component takes in a form that has a nested field matching the provided schema.

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { NestedForm, nestedForm } from './nestedForm';

const nestedSchema = z.object({
  value1: z.string(),
  value2: z.string(),
});

const schema = z.object({
  nested: nestedSchema,
});

export type NestedSchemaType = z.input<typeof nestedSchema>;
export type SchemaType = z.input<typeof schema>;

type NestedFormComponentProps = {
  form1: NestedForm<{ value1: string; value2: string }>;
  form2: NestedForm<{ value1: string; [x: string]: any }>;
  form3: NestedForm<Record<string, any>>;
  form4: NestedForm<Record<any, any>>;
};

export function NestedFormComponent({ form1, form2, form3, form4 }: NestedFormComponentProps) {
  return <></>;
}

export function Form() {
  const form = useForm<SchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });

  const nested = nestedForm(form, 'nested');

  return (
    <NestedFormComponent
      form1={nested} // Works
      form2={nested} //  // Property 'value2' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: any; value1: string; }' but required in type '{ value1: string; value2: string; }'
      form3={nested} //  // Type 'Record<string, any>' is missing the following properties from type '{ value1: string; value2: string; }': value1, value2
      form4={nested} //  // Type 'Record<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type '{ value1: string; value2: string; }': value1, value2
    />;
}
```

Passing `nested` to `form1` works, as the types of the nested Zod schema and the type passed to `NestedForm<>` match. However, it doesn't work if the `NestedForm<>` type does not exactly match the type of the provided path.

`form2`, `form3`, and `form4` all give type errors. The errors don't make sense to me. Shouldn't `Record<any, any>` allow every possible property? Why is TS giving an error saying that it is missing some properties?